# UIButton selector not recognized by the following method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, selector

I have declared a method at the selector and I created a method with the same name. Yet, the method says it is not recognisable. The error messages:

[image: code]

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_favorite_border_48pt.png"];
    UIButton *heart = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    // get the image size and apply it to the button frame
    CGRect listButtonFrame = heart.frame;
    listButtonFrame.size = btnImage.size;
    heart.frame = listButtonFrame;

    [heart setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [heart addTarget:self.navigationController.parentViewController
                   action:@selector(revealToggle:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *jobsButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:heart];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = jobsButton;


    -(void)revealToggle:(UIButton *)heart
    {

    }
```

Comment: Objective-C doesn't support nested methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have put the `revealToggle` method inside your `viewDidAppear` method. You can't do that. Move it outside.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_favorite_border_48pt.png"];
    UIButton *heart = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    // get the image size and apply it to the button frame
    CGRect listButtonFrame = heart.frame;
    listButtonFrame.size = btnImage.size;
    heart.frame = listButtonFrame;

    [heart setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [heart addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(revealToggle:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *jobsButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:heart];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = jobsButton;
}

-(void)revealToggle:(UIButton *)heart
{

}
```

And since `revealToggle` is inside this same class, you need to pass `self` as the target.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy, you are sharp. Didn't realise my method was inside viewDidAppear, was so puzzled earlier.

Comment: i didn't see that +1